# Не меняется цена товара в Quick View WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Дано:** магазин, принципиально требуется использовать QuickView (в данном случае плагин "Direct Checkout | Quick View | Buy Now For WooCommerce" [ссылка на плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-view-and-buy-now-for-woocommerce/) в комбинации с "Extra Product Options for WooCommerce" [ссылка на плагин](https://www.themehigh.com/product/woocommerce-extra-product-options/)). Extra Product Options for WooCommerce взят для множественного выбора добавок, он не требует создания вариативного товара (изображение и описание ниже). Родительская тема - StoreFront.

**Проблема:** при выборе вариаций в popup-окне значение цены визуально не меняется, хотя по итогу добавлен в корзину товар будет с верной ценой и учётом выбранных вариантов. В обычной карточке товара всё отрабатывает как надо.

Первый скрин - в popup-окне Quick View

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь работа плагина на странице товара - всё верно, цена изменяется.

[image: Extra Product Options for WooCommerce на странице товара отрабатывает верно]

**Собственно вопрос**: как сделать чтобы цена динамически менялась в зависимости от выбранных опций в окне быстрого просмотра?

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему. Не сильно силён в PHP, в основном работаю плагинами.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для начала смотри ошибки в консоли браузера и в логах сервера. И по результату (или сразу) может быть подбери другой плагин. ЗЫ, Хорошим тоном считается оставлять ссылку на плагин. Особенно если он в репо.

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за комментарий. Пост дополнил скринами и ссылками.

Ошибок в консоли и логах нет.

Комбинации плагинов пробовал разные, довольно много. Сделать товар вариативным пытался тоже.
Итог один и тот же - на странице товара цена динамически меняется, в popup - нет.

Comment: Проверил с твоим плагом QW и [этим](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpc-product-options/)  для опций. Эта связка работает.  https://i.imgur.com/tzyCqZp.gif

Comment: Кстати у WPC есть много других полезных плагов, в тч и QuickView. Возможно это будет лучше, чем выбранные тобой монстры.

Comment: @SeVlad работает как надо! Спасибо тебе огромное и всех благ!